# Enabling view programmatically

Tags: views

I want to know how to enable view programmatically in drupal 7? I need it to be exportable with features. I need a snippet code for that. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you actually are looking for, is it just to "enable" a view (that you have somewhere)? If you want to learn from examples (the various pieces it takes for a module to come with a view), then have a look at the sample views that come with the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module .

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I honestly think you are doing something wrong, but if you really do have a legit use case I think you can just do this:

```
$view = views_get_view('machine-name-of-view');
views_export_status($view, TRUE);
views_save_view($view);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I needed it to run hook update that is going ti enable one and disable second view,